# Расскажите пожалуйста про основные функции кортежа

Tags: кортежи

помогите я начинающий на пайтоне

Comment: Ну, кортеж хранит в себе одно или несколько значений. Вот и всё, наверное?

Answer (score 1):

Ну по сути кортеж-это тот же список, только статичный, то есть его нельзя изменить(добавить или удалить элементы и тд). Обычно его использует вместо списка, если важно, чтобы данные внутри не были случайно изменены в ходе работы. Я если что сам не профи, может скилловые программисты знают какие-то еще секретные особенности кортежей.

Comment: для ответов на такие вопросы вполне достаточно оставить комментарий под ним, а не писать в качестве полноценного ответа, так как почти 100% данный вопрос будет закрыт

Comment: @ZxNuClear - я бы с радостью, но у меня пока не хватает репутации, чтоб оставлять комменты, поэтому пришлось как ответ оставить(